# Autosubmit form via JS (Timeout, TimeInterval)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, timeout

I want to create simple auto submit. For example if user 1 sec don't type anything in input or press enter it's submit. My code:

```js
$(document).on('keypress', $('input'), function(e) {
  console.log('clear')
  
  clearInterval(SubmitInterval);
  
  if (e.which == 13) {
    console.log('submit')
  }
  
  var SubmitInterval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('submit')
    clearInterval(SubmitInterval);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=1 />
```

But it work badly.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to you redefining the `SubmitInterval` variable on each keypress. Instead declare that once, outside the event handler. Try this:

```js
var submitInterval;

$(document).on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
  console.log('clear')
  
  clearInterval(submitInterval);
  
  if (e.which == 13) {
    console.log('submit')
  }
  
  submitInterval = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('submit')
    clearInterval(submitInterval);
  }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text id=1 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Now all works fine. Thanks.

```js
var SubmitInterval;
$(document).on('keypress', $('input'), function(e) {
  clearInterval(SubmitInterval);
  SubmitInterval = setInterval(function () {
    console.log('submit');
    clearInterval(SubmitInterval);
  },1700);
  if(e.which == 13) {
   console.log('submit');
   clearInterval(SubmitInterval);
 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=text />
```